# how to call a VScript file (.vscript file extension) in C# Windows application

Tags: c#

I need to call a VScript file (.vscript file extension) in my C# Windows application. How can I do this?

Comment: what is a vscript? link?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a .vscript file is, but if you would normally run it by double-clicking it, you can simply do:

```
  var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("myscript.vscript");
  process.WaitForExit();  // if you want to wait, otherwise, leave this out
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `.vbs`? That is a Visual Basic Script file.
Anyway, to call it you might want to use the following lines. This method is also fool-proof. Some people might have assigned `.vbs` to a different program.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("wscript.exe \"" + filepath + "\"").WaitForExit();
```

If you also want a console, I *think* it is `csript.exe` instead of `wscript.exe`.

Anyways, whether your file is **really** `.vscript` or not, `wcript.exe` and `cscript.exe` will run it.